# NullPointerException when saving entity with non-null foreign key in Spring Boot and JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, java-17

I'm encountering an issue in my Spring Boot application where I'm getting a NullPointerException when trying to save an entity with a non-null foreign key using JPA. I have a HistoriaClinica entity that has a many-to-one relationship with a Paciente entity. The foreign key column paciente_id is not nullable in the database.

However, when I attempt to save a new HistoriaClinica entity with a valid pacienteId, I'm getting a NullPointerException with the error message: "The given id must not be null". I've checked and confirmed that the pacienteId is not null and exists in the database.

I've reviewed my code and verified that the mapping and annotations for the relationship between Paciente and HistoriaClinica are set correctly. I've also checked the database configuration and ensured that the necessary tables and columns are present.

I'm using Spring Boot 3.0.5 and JPA for my persistence layer. I've included the relevant code snippets below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "historias_clinicas")
@Getter
@Setter
public class HistoriaClinica {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fecha_creacion", nullable = false)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date fechaCreacion;

    private String enfermedad;

    private String descripcion;

    private String medicacion;
    
    private String droga;
    
    private String dósis;
    
    private Double peso;
    
    private Double altura;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String indicaciones;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "paciente_id", nullable = false)
    private Paciente paciente;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "historiaClinica", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ArchivoHistoriaClinica> archivosHistoriaClinica;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "historiaClinica", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Actualizacion> actualizaciones = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "historiaClinica", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ArchivoHistoriaClinica> archivos = new ArrayList<>();
//respective constructors
```

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Paciente {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String apellido;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String dni;
    
    @Column(name = "fecha_nacimiento")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate fechaNacimiento;
    
    private String direccion;
    
    private String telefono;
    
    private String email;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String role = "ROLE_PACIENTE"; // anotación de rol

    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "paciente", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<HistoriaClinica> historiasClinicas;

    public Paciente() {
    }
```

The HistoriaClinicaService method that i'm calling:

```
 public HistoriaClinica save(HistoriaClinicaDTO hcDTO, Long idPaciente) {
        Paciente paciente = pacienteRepository.findById(idPaciente)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Paciente no encontrado con id " + idPaciente));

        HistoriaClinica hc = historiaClinicaMapper.toEntity(hcDTO);
        hc.setPaciente(paciente);

        List<Actualizacion> actualizaciones = hcDTO.getActualizaciones().stream()
                .map(actualizacionMapper::toEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        hc.setActualizaciones(actualizaciones);

        List<ArchivoHistoriaClinica> archivos = hcDTO.getArchivos().stream()
                .map(archivoHistoriaClinicaMapper::toEntity)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        hc.setArchivos(archivos);
        actualizaciones.forEach(actualizacion -> actualizacion.setHistoriaClinica(hc));
        archivos.forEach(archivo -> archivo.setHistoriaClinica(hc));

        entityManager.persist(hc);
        return hc;
    }
```

And the endpoint:

```
@PostMapping("/nuevas/{idPaciente}")
public ResponseEntity<HistoriaClinicaDTO> createHistoriaClinica(@RequestBody HistoriaClinicaDTO historiaClinicaDTO, @PathVariable("idPaciente") Long pacienteId) {
    // Verificar si el paciente existe
    Optional<Paciente> pacienteOptional = pacienteService.buscarPorId(pacienteId);
    if (!pacienteOptional.isPresent()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No se encontró un paciente con el ID proporcionado.");
    }

    HistoriaClinica nuevaHistoriaClinica = historiaClinicaService.save(historiaClinicaDTO, pacienteId);

    HistoriaClinicaDTO newHistoriaClinicaDTO = historiaClinicaMapper.toDto(nuevaHistoriaClinica);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(newHistoriaClinicaDTO);
}
```

I have tried debugging the code and inspecting the values at each step, but I haven't been able to identify the root cause of the NullPointerException. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here's what I have checked so far:

- The "Paciente" entity has a generated "id" field, and it is assigned automatically when saving a new instance.
- The "HistoriaClinica" entity has a Many-to-One relationship with "Paciente", and the association is properly defined with the "paciente_id" foreign key.
- When retrieving the "Paciente" from the repository, it is successfully found and returned.
- I have verified that the "Paciente" object has a valid ID before setting it in the "HistoriaClinica" entity.
- I have checked the database, and the associated "Paciente" record exists with a valid ID.
- Despite these checks, I still encounter the "NullPointerException" with the message stating that "pacienteId must not be null" when trying to persist the "HistoriaClinica" entity.

Comment: [Edit] your post and include the complete stack trace (format as code).  Find the statement _in your code_ that caused the exception, and indicate that statement clearly in your code listing.